# VBA CSV Import Code in Shared Network not working on co-workers connections

Tags: vba, excel, csv, import

I have coded a csv import file that imports and sorts information, but the import section of the code is being skipped with no errors on a co-workers computer and not mine. We both access the same file in the same folder on the same shared network, but for some reason we are not running the code the same.

There are no error codes, and we set up his connection to the shared network using the same network folder: N:\12ABC\PROGRAM\Main (Put CSVs Here)

```
 Sub ImportAllCSV()
  Dim FName As Variant, R As Long
  R = 1
  FName = Dir("*.csv")
  Do While FName <> ""
    ImportCsvFile FName, ActiveSheet.Cells(R, 1)
    R = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.count + 1
    FName = Dir
  Loop
End Sub

Sub ImportCsvFile(FileName As Variant, Position As Range)
  With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
      "TEXT;" & FileName _
      , Destination:=Position)
      .Name = Replace(FileName, ".csv", "")
      .FieldNames = True
      .RowNumbers = False
      .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
      .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
      .BackgroundQuery = True
      .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
      .SavePassword = False
      .SaveData = True
      .AdjustColumnWidth = True
      .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
      .TextFilePlatform = xlMacintosh
      .TextFileStartRow = 1
      .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
      .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
      .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
      .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
      .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
      .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
      .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
      .TextFileOtherDelimiter = ","
      .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
      .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
  End With
End Sub
```

Please help! Thank you

Comment: It sounds like it's never entering the Do While loop. Is it? Do you know how to step through the code using the `F8` key?

Comment: When I step through the code it highlights the Do While loop and the next step is end-sub. First time stepping through the code, so im not sure what that means.

Comment: Meanwhile for some reason the same file works normally on the computer it was created on. Mine.

Comment: It means the condition isn't true. Can you actually see a file with a CSV extension in that folder on their computer? Maybe they have file extensions turned off in Windows Explorer - I can't remember if that would be an issue.

Comment: So the computer that holds the working version doesn't even need to display file extensions. Nonetheless adding that feature didn't change anything.

Comment: If your answer to my question above is "yes" then I'm out of ideas. For some reason the code isn't seeing any CSV files in that folder on that computer. Good luck!

Comment: Are you actually telling it what folder to look in? because if not it will use the current directory which may well be different (you'd never assume the current directory, always set it).

Comment: I included a specific directory in FName = Dir("\something\*.csv")
This allowed the code to run into the loop, but now we are stuck on the .Refresh command at the end of the ImportCsvFile FName section of the loop.

Comment: And "Yes" I can see CSV file extensions in the folder. The weird thing is that (Before I added a specific path directory) my co-workers run of the code pulled a csv file from another random folder. After adding the specific directory they are all stuck on the .Refresh.